# ngx-charts timeline: get selected period

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

When using the timeline feature in ngx-charts and selecting a range in order to zoom in, is there a way (a callback or event listener) that can return the subset of data or period that you are looking at?

I basically have a table and a graph representing the same timeseries data. When i use the timeline, I would like the table data to also be filtered for the selected period. I wonder if there's a way to do this.

Sort of what flot charts gives you in this example: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/selection/index.html